# What’s the difference between Unit and Normalization concept in terms of vectors?

Tags: unit-of-measure

I understand Unit concept as a measurement concept, so when we say Unit vector we mean it’s the smallest vector(**and it’s length always equal one**) and we can measure other vectors in terms of it.

For Normalization, the concept of normalization as I understand it is “return” the values of that thing to be in $[0,1]$ interval, so when we normalize a vector we divide it by it’s length to get a vector that inside that interval, and **it’s length not necessarily equals one**.

I’m I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you normalize a vector in a normed vector space $(V,||.||)$ you actually apply the mapping:
$$V\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow S^1,v\mapsto\frac{1}{||v||}v $$
where $S^1=\{v\in V:||v||=1\}$ is the unit sphere. Clearly
$$||\frac{1}{||v||}v||=\frac{||v||}{||v||}=1$$ for all $v\in V\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: So, in conclusion: in normed vector space there is no difference between “unit” and “normalization”?

Comment: Or let' s say normalization is the mapping that maps every non-zero vector on its correspondent unit vector